# How can I blend together non-tileable images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending, tiles

I have a section of a continuous image copy and pasted, but it is not tileable.  How can I blend the segments together so that it looks like one piece?  I have tried using the auto-blend layers feature, but that just makes things worse.  (Each segment is on its own layer.)

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the sections are in order and in different layers,:

- Duplicate the top layer and move it down vertically until place in the middle
- Click the copied layer and drag it to the mask icon located at the bottom of the Layers Panel to create a **Mask**

[image: MaskIcon]

- Click the **Mask Thumbnail**
- Get the **Gradient Tool** and fill the mask white area with a Reflex Gradient black/white/black

[image: Gradient Mask]

- Repeat every two layers

[image: animation]

- Select all the layers and **Merge** them from **Menu Layer** (or duplicate them and merge)
- Select the center area and go to **Menu Filter** > **Noise** > **Median**

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Move the copied layer to the mask icon? I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you.  I am getting closer.  One more thing I don't understand:  "and move it down vertically until be place in the middle".

Comment: If you duplicate the layer 7, move the duplicate layer vertically down until locating it in the middle of the layers 6 and 7

Comment: In situations where there's a very small amount of a pattern to repeat, it can make sense to add an additional texture on top. Here's an example where I took Daniello's end-result and put a random "crumpled paper texture" layer on top with blend mode: multiple, lowered opacity and posterize adjustment (my example left): [**Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp9in.png). This is where context helps. I don't know if that is supposed to be paper, but to me, it looked like a sort of video gamey paper scroll type of thing.

Comment: @Evorlor, check it out, forgot to mention you in my comment above ↑

Answer (score 0):

Watching this case another time:

It seems some kind of joke. I selected the 2nd stripe from the top with the rectangle selection tool and flipped the area horizontally. The result fits . Now it's a repeating pattern.

[image]

**ADD:** The discussion in the comments reveals that it's not a joke. The questioner had originally too small piece of a texture - something like this, I guess:

[image]

He needed more, but simply repeating it wasn't any good. Then he made smaller slices, flipped some of them horizontally and asked, how to fade the borders of the slices. The goal was to get something non-repeating but to keep the style.

A solution to the original problem (without painting the missing area from scratch) is to copy smaller areas from the original by cloning and copy& paste. Pasted areas are new layers before merging them - so they can be scaled and rotated freely and that's done here.

Variatons can be made and the cutting edges can be faded with the smudge brush as long as the pasted parts are independent layers. Healing brush fade easily sharp borders after merging.

The green stripes can be pulled with smudge brush (make a selection before)

Lighted areas at the paper edges can be made with a curves adjustment layer. In the layer mask white allows the brightening to occur.

[image]

Comment: That's because I copied and pasted it a bunch, and rotated it so that it would not look so repeating.

Comment: @Evorlor So you have only a little piece of original and want a bigger area of same looking texture which does not seem a series of copies?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Evorlor Consider to add rhe revealed things to the question - you have a possiblity to get an answer for the actual goal.

Comment: I received an answer to my question. The fact that I'm a newb, and I should not have taken the approach that got me here, is irrelevant to my question and the answer.